# Выгрузка каталога товаров из 1с

Tags: 1с

Добрый день, друзья! У меня к вам такой вопрос, как включить в выгрузку товаров цены? 1с стоит 11.1, выгрузку делаю через Администрирование->Настройки синхронизации данных->Узлы обмена данных с сайтами. Сделал узел обмена данными с сайтом, а также узел обмена для передачи на локальный компьютер. При просмотре передаваемых данных цены на товары отсутствуют, хотя они указаны в "Цены номенклатуры".

Вот скрины того как я настраиваю все это:

[image]

[image]

В результате импорта получаю примерно такую структуру описания товаров:

```
<Товар>
                <Ид>ac4f7aba-49e4-11e4-a04f-d850e63f3cf1</Ид>
                <Штрихкод>штрихкод3</Штрихкод>
                <Артикул>Семейная открытка</Артикул>
                <Наименование>Семейная открытка</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796" НаименованиеПолное="Штука" МеждународноеСокращение="PCE">шт</БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Группы>
                    <Ид>ac4f7aa8-49e4-11e4-a04f-d850e63f3cf1</Ид>
                </Группы>
                <СтавкиНалогов>
                    <СтавкаНалога>
                        <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                        <Ставка>18</Ставка>
                    </СтавкаНалога>
                </СтавкиНалогов>
                <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ВидНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар (пр. ТМЦ)</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Код</Наименование>
                        <Значение>00-00000004</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Полное наименование</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Семейная открытка</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
            </Товар>
```

Объясните, мне пожалуйста, где можно настроить так, чтобы в выгрузку включалась цена товара? С 1с плохо знаком, потому требуется помощь тех, кто работал с этим и хорошо знает эти проблемы.

Comment: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum26/topic47278/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для выгрузки цен на сайт в УТ 11 нужно настроить цены. Цены будут располагаться в файле offers.xml
Неплохая пошаговая инструкция находится [тут](http://www.divier.ru/stati/vygruzka_v_bitriks_instruktsii/vygruzka_v_bitriks_iz_1s_upravlenie_torgovley_11_1_2_9.html).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Правда, я уже эту инструкцию читал, в файле offers.xml нет ничего, кроме общей коммерческой информации. Прочитаю еще раз, может что-то упустил, потому что хотелось бы до ума довести задачу...

Comment: Внимательно взгляни на справочник "Типовые соглашения с клиентом". Должна быть обязательно установлена галочка "Доступно внешним пользователям". Такое соглашение создается для всех видов цен, которые переносятся на сайт.
P.S. Также нужно, чтобы цены были! :) (Заполнен документ "Установка цен номенклатуры".)